# Get SKDocument by URL

Tags: swift, macos, cocoa, searchkit

SearchKit is an API that's beyond weird. There seems to be no method to get a specific `SKDocument` by its URL. Rather I'd have to iterate over all documents and remember their `SKDocumentID`s and `URL`s myself.

Is this correct?

Comment: How about `SKIndexGetDocumentID`?

Comment: I need the document first to get the ID. Which is why I want to look up the document by its URL.

Comment: Create a `SKDocument` with `SKDocumentCreateWithURL()`.

Comment: It's like talking to a wall... I want to QUERY by URL not to create it. Documents are already existing.

Comment: From the documentation of `SKDocument`: "Defines an opaque data type representing a document’s URL." and "A document URL object is a generic location specification for a document. It is built from a document scheme, a parent document, and a document name. You can convert back and forth between document URL objects and CFURL objects using Search Kit’s SKDocumentCreateWithURL(_:) and SKDocumentCopyURL(_:) functions.". The `SKDocument…` functions use the url: "the document URL object".